# element ui tables with pagination

Tags: javascript, vue.js, element-ui

problem with element ui ,when I select checkbox and change page , the selection rows checkbox removed , I need to Keep selection items while I am changing pages. I mean the user Can Select items from many pages without losing items in previous pages.

```
        <el-table
        ref="multipleTable"
      row-key="id"
      :key="tableKey"
      v-loading="listLoading"
      :data="list"
      border
      fit
      style="width: 100%;"
    @select="myselect"
    @sort-change="sortChange"
      @selection-change="handleSelectionChange"
    :tree-props="{children: 'children'}"
    >




.......

      <pagination v-show="total>0" :total="total" :page.sync="listQuery.page" :limit.sync="listQuery.limit" @pagination="getList" />
      <pagination v-show="total>0" :total="total" :page.sync="listQuery.page" :limit.sync="listQuery.limit" @pagination="getList" />


and these functions
      myselect(selection, row) {
        console.log('this is selection', selection);
        console.log('this is row', row)
      },





  handleSelectionChange(val) {
    this.selectedShipments = val;
    window.localStorage.setItem('storedShipments', JSON.stringify(this.selectedShipments));
      },

    async getList() {
     this.listLoading = true;
     const { data } = await fetchShipmentList(this.listQuery);
      this.list = data.data;
      this.total = data.total;
      // Just to simulate the time of the request
     this.listLoading = false;
    },




   listQuery: {
        page: 1,
        limit: 10,
        search: undefined,
        status: undefined,
        sort: 'id',
        sortDir:'desc',
      },
```

Answer (score 2):

use reserve-selection:whether to reserve selection after data refreshing, works when type is 'selection'. Note that row-key is required for this to work

```
<el-table
  v-loading="listLoading"
  :data="list.slice((currentPage-1)*pagesize,currentPage*pagesize)"
  element-loading-text="Loading"
  border
  fit
  highlight-current-row
  @selection-change="handleSelectionChange"
  :row-key="getRowKey"
>
  <el-table-column type="selection" width="40" :reserve-selection="true" />

getRowKey(row){
  return row.id
},
```

Answer (score 0):

https://element.eleme.io/#/en-US/component/table

you shall call toggleRowSelection on your table for each selected item in your selectedShipments array.

It should look like

```js
    async getList() {
     this.listLoading = true;
     const { data } = await fetchShipmentList(this.listQuery);
      this.list = data.data;
      this.total = data.total;
      // Just to simulate the time of the request
     this.listLoading = false;
     // I think it should be done after refresh
     this.$nextTick(()=>{
  this.selectedShipments.forEach(r=>this.$refs.multipleTable.toggleRowSelection(r,true))
     })
    },
```

Comment: it is same result , also I have sub with all rows is this effect.?